# python threads hangs but no exception

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, freeze

I'm using threads with queue, the loop contains like 6000 items but it suddenly hangs in 5000 or more and never continue although no thread through any exception code is as below

```
def extract_data():
    while True:
       empty_flag = False
       try:
           id = q2.get(timeout = 60)
       except Empty:
           empty_flag = True

      if not empty_flag:
           "do some processing here"

           q2.task_done()





threads_number = 5
q2 = Queue(threads_number * 2)
for i in range(threads_number):
    t = Thread(target=extract_data)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

try:
    for i,nbd in enumerate(lst[0:],0):  --> list contains 6000 itemts
        print "%d of %d\r" %(i+1,len(new_nbds)),   --> print hangs here in item (5898 of 6000) or hangs when finish and never end (6000 of 6000)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        q2.put(nbd)

    q2.join()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run as is.  I made it work by adding appropriate imports, adding `list = list(range(6000))`, etc. but couldn't reproduce the issue.  Please provide code that reproduces the problem (read this -> [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

your Queue size is for `10 element` and you are pushing `6000 element` from a loop even though you are popping it concurrently from five different threads. I doubt during pushing and popping from the loop and thread respectively there is a synchronization issue arise and it leads to deadlock. Make the Queue size bigger that might solve your issue. Like `q2 = Queue(threads_number * 10)`

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for reply, the problem was when one thread was trying to download document using requests module, requests.get keep running infinitely without returning any errors or data, adding stream=True solved the problem